# Python - how do I write a "getter" function that will return a variable stored in my module (initiating it first if needed)?

Tags: python

Here is the complete code of my module, called `util.py`:

```
import my_other_module

__IMPORTANT_OBJECT__ = None

def getImportantObject():
    if __IMPORTANT_OBJECT__ is None:
        __IMPORTANT_OBJECT__ = my_other_module.ImportantObject()
    return __IMPORTANT_OBJECT__
```

My understanding is that variables prefixed with a double underscore are considered private to a module.  The idea here is that I would like to store a private reference to the important object and the return it to anyone who asks for it via the `getImportantObject()` method.  But I don't want the object to be initiated until the first time this method is called.

When I run my code, however, I get the following error:

```
File "/Users/Jon/dev/util.py", line 6, in getImportantObject
    if __IMPORTANT_OBJECT__ is None:
UnboundLocalError: local variable '__IMPORTANT_OBJECT__' referenced before assignment
```

What is the recommended way to accomplish what I am trying to do here?

Comment: You shouldn't invent new ``__dunder__`` names, they are reserved to the Python interpreter, btw.

Comment: Thanks, Ned.  What should I do instead?  I'd like the variable to be private (at least by convention, if not strictly enforced by Python).

Comment: @JonCrowell: use only leading underscores, not trailing: `__IMPORTANT_OBJECT`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable is not considered private; rather it's seen as a local variable.

Use the `global` keyword to mark it as such:

```
def getImportantObject():
    global __IMPORTANT_OBJECT__
    if __IMPORTANT_OBJECT__ is None:
        __IMPORTANT_OBJECT__ = my_other_module.ImportantObject()
    return __IMPORTANT_OBJECT__
```

Comment: I tried this and I got the same error.  `UnboundLocalError: local variable '__IMPORTANT_OBJECT__' referenced before assignment`

Comment: @JonCrowell: Double check what you did. You probably mistyped the variable name.

Comment: You're right, I did!  But now I'm getting `NameError: global name '__IMPORTANT_OBJECT__' is not defined`

Comment: @JonCrowell: So now it is not matching the module-scope variable assignment (`__IMPORTANT_OBJECT__ = None`). The names have to match!

Comment: I am looking at my code very closely.  The variable name appears one time each in the first, second, third, and fourth lines of the functions.  I have confirmed that they are identical in every case.  (If I search and highlight, the variable names in all four lines match and get highlighted, so they must be identical) I have removed the trailing underscores (per your comment above).  So I have `__IMPORTANT_OBJECT` in every line and the error points to the line `if __IMPORTANT_OBJECT is None:` and tells me `NameError: global name '__IMPORTANT_OBJECT' is not defined

Comment: @JonCrowell: Which means, that in the module scope, there is no variable named `__IMPORTANT_OBJECT`. I can't say anything else without seeing your code.

Comment: Ahh, okay, I understand now.  I had assumed that in your original answer you were telling me to move the variable declaration inside the function and that Python did something magic with the `global` keyword to make it a global variable even though it was defined in the function.  But I guess what is going on is that I have to declare the variable outside the function and then tell my function that I want to refer to the global variable.

Comment: @Jon Crowell: When you changed the name from `__IMPORTANT_OBJECT__` to `__IMPORTANT_OBJECT` in some contexts the Python interpreter might change the name (mangle it) by adding another prefix because it thinks it's a private _class_ name. Try changing it to just have one leading underscore, i.e. `_IMPORTANT_OBJECT`.

Comment: @martineau: The problem has already been resolved; the `__IMPORTANT_OBJECT__ = None` line at module level was removed; a misunderstanding.